# Flutter iOS build stuck on "Attaching to Runner on iPhone"

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

When I try to build my Flutter app on a real iOS device, the build executes without any errors, and the app gets installed on the device, but it never opens. It gets stuck on the step "Attaching to Runner" and stays on that step until I stop the build.

I get no error message at all.

Anyone with a clue what I might be doing wrong?